# How to make "\input" in a "\include"-d file use the correct current path?

Tags: input, include, folders

I'm having a master file let's say `test.tex` and also some folders `sub1/` and `sub2/`. There is also a TeX file in each of them: `sub1/sub1.tex` and `sub2/sub2.tex`. In the `sub1/` and `sub2/` are also some snippets `sub1/snip11.tikz`, `sub1/snip12.tikz`, `sub2/snip21.tikz` and `sub2/snip22.tikz`. The files look like following:

#### `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\section{sub1}
\include{sub1/sub1}

\section{sub2}
\include{sub2/sub2}

\end{document}
```

#### `sub1/sub1.tex`:

```
\input{snip11.tikz}
\input{snip12.tikz}
```

#### `sub2/sub2.tex`:

```
\input{snip21.tikz}
\input{snip22.tikz}
```

The `snip??.tikz` contain some `tikzpicture` like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,1) arc (90:130:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If one tries to compile it, it will obviously fail, because while being in `sub1/sub1.tex` the `\input` command will look for `snip11.tikz` in the root folder instead of in the folder `sub1/`.

Is there any way to make `\input` look in the same folder as the folder in which the containing TeX file is located?

Of course I could add the correct path in the `sub1/sub1.tex`, but I'm having tons of subfolders and also this is not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Note that the `\section` commands should be in their respective included files, else you get a section title alone on a page. (And of course I recommend import.sty.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The FAQ suggests the packages `import` or `chapterfolder`:

https://texfaq.org/FAQ-docotherdir

Comment: I tried it and although it looks like the correct solution it won't work.

Comment: I made an error. I tried \import instead of \include and now it works and seems like the corect solution for this issue.

Comment: The link you've shared is now at its own domain: [texfaq.org](https://texfaq.org/) Awesome website! thx

Answer (score 6):

It's not so easy to make `\input` work from a relative directory as the TeX macro layer doesn't know where your `sub`.tex` is, it could be anywhere in the TEXINPUTS path. But you may use the same feature if your TEXINPUTS setting (environment variable or texmf.cnf setting) includes .//
then Tex will recursively search all subdirectories for each file, so as long as your filenames are distinct it doesn't matter which subdirectory they are in.

so

```
$ latex test
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (Web2C 2010)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2009-06-19, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabic, armenian
, basque....

! LaTeX Error: File `hmm.tex' not found.
```

but setting the path:

```
$ TEXINPUTS=";.//" latex test
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (Web2C 2010)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2009-06-19, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabic, armenian
, basque,...
(./sub1/hmm.tex
```

here the file `hmm.tex` has been found in the subdirectory.

`test.tex` here is just

```
 \input{hmm}
```

Here TEXINPUTS has been changed on the command line just for this command (bash syntax) that may or may not be available depending on your system but you will be able to set TEXINPUTS *somewhere*.

Answer (score 4):

If you only have files with different name in all your subfolders, I would suggest getting rid of the subfolder calls in your main document and only calling `\input{file}` while adding the relevant folders to the environment variable `TEXINPUTS` like:

```
TEXINPUTS=".:./sub1:./sub2:./sub3:$TEXINPUTS" latex main.tex
```

you can include path for graphics included with `\includegraphics{}` as well as it also plays the role of the `\graphicspath{}` command.

If you have two files with the same name in two different subfolders, then it might be a bit more tricky.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a potential solution that uses a variable that is changed each time a new file is loaded. It should work for any number of subfolders.

For your main file, **`test.tex`**:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}

%these are the relevant lines%
\newcommand\subfolder{}      
\newcommand\rinclude[2]{
\renewcommand\subfolder{#1} 
\include{#1/#2}}
\newcommand\rinput[1]{
\input{\subfolder/#1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\section{sub1}
\rinclude{sub1}{sub1}

\section{sub2}
\rinclude{sub2}{sub2}

\end{document}
```

Then, in your **`sub1/sub1.tex`** file you would use:

```
\rinput{snip11.tikz}
\rinput{snip12.tikz}
```

Likewise, in your **`sub2/sub2.tex`** file:

```
\rinput{snip21.tikz}
\rinput{snip22.tikz}
```

For this solution you would simply use the new command `\rinclude` instead of `\include` and in your `.tex` files in the subfolders, used `\rinput` instead of `\input`. The first argument for the `\rinclude` command is the subfolder and the second argument is the filename. Arguments for `\rinput` are the same as for `\input`.

Comment: It actually worked, but the solution with the package import seems more straightforward.