# Use one tex file in different documents

Tags: graphics, input

I want to write a tex file which can be used in serveral higher order documents, but there are problems with the relative paths of the figures.

Example:
In folder `sub1` is the file `base1.tex` which uses a figure from folder `pics1` via a relative path `../pics1/figure.pdf`. I want to use the file `base1.tex` via input in 'main1.tex' in folder `documents` (two layers higher than `sub1`) and in a second file 'details.tex' in folder `sub1`. For more details the folder structure:

```
documents

-part1

--sub1
--sub2
--pics1
--pics2
```

The problem is, that the relative path in `base1.tex` is only correct in one document. Is there a way to add the input path (`input{./part1/sub1/base1.tex}`) to the relative path (`\includegraphics{../pics1/figure.pdf}`) in the `base1.tex` file?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise.  A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52486/15925 .  If that helps, let us know and we will close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Thats the same problem, therefore this question can be closed as duplicate.

Comment: Make sure to consider upvoting the question and the answer there if they helped you.